# Child theme undefined variable error

Tags: child-theme

I'm trying to make my own child theme from Twenty Fifteen.
Everything looks and functions fine, but when I turn on debugging, I can see a PHP error:

```
Undefined variable: parent_style
```

on line 13 of functions.php of my child theme.

Here is the content of the functions.php file.

```
<?php /*

  This file is part of a child theme called spch.
  Functions in this file will be loaded before the parent theme's functions.
  For more information, please read https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes.

*/

// this code loads the parent's stylesheet (leave it in place unless you know what you're doing)

function theme_enqueue_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style('parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css');
    wp_enqueue_style('child-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css', array($parent_style));
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_styles');

/*  Add your own functions below this line.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this line you use variable called `$parent_style`

```
wp_enqueue_style('child-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css', array($parent_style));
```

but you don’t define such variable anywhere in your code.

Most probably you want to use the slug of parent style instead:

```
wp_enqueue_style('child-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css', array('parent-style'));
```

Comment: Thank you for that explanation. I change the code as you suggested, and it works now.